# How to create page in pages library using custom pagelayout in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How to create page in pages library using custom page layout in SharePoint 2013?
I had created page layout already, I just need to use that page layout and create page using this custom page layout in SharePoint using visual studio?

Comment: You can add feature activated event receiver in solution and add page creation code in activated event receiver. You can get info about page creation from this URL: http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-a-Publishing-Page-Programmatically-in-SharePoint-2013

Answer (score 2):

use below code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                string currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Title;
                string strPageURL = "MyNewPage.aspx";
                string strPageTitle = "MyCustomPage";
                string strCreatedPageURL = string.Empty;
                string layoutName = GetLayoutName("Article Page");

                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                    {
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite oPublishingSite = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite(oSite);

                        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList PagesList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Pages");

                        if (PagesList != null)
                        {
                            Guid PagesID = PagesList.ID;
                            web.AllProperties["__PagesListId"] = PagesID.ToString();
                            //web.Update();
                            //web.AllProperties["__PublishingFeatureActivated"] = "True";
                            //web.Update();

                            Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb oPublishingWeb = Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

                            Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayoutCollection layoutCollection = oPublishingSite.GetPageLayouts(false);

                            Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout layout = layoutCollection[layoutName];

                            Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage page = oPublishingWeb.GetPublishingPage(web.Url + "/Pages/" + strPageURL);

                            if (page == null)
                            {
                                page = oPublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(strPageURL, layout);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception("A page with the given URL already exists. Please try a different URL");
                            }

                            if (page.ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser == null)
                            {
                                page.CheckOut();
                            }


                            page.Title = strPageTitle;
                            page.Update();
                            page.CheckIn("Page Created");


                            //page.ListItem.File.Publish("Page Published");

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            strCreatedPageURL = web.Url + "/Pages/" + strPageURL;
                        }



                    }
                });


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        private string GetLayoutName(string contentTypeName)
        {
            string layoutURL = string.Empty;
            switch (contentTypeName)
            {
                case "Article":
                    layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/About CAA.aspx";
                    break;
                case "Convention":
                    layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/About CAA.aspx";
                    break;

                default:
                    layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/About CAA.aspx";
                    break;
            }

            return layoutURL;
        }
```